# javascript, running a function when a childnode is clicked

Tags: javascript

So I have this code that works.

```js
<head><title> Matching game asessment</title></head><style>img{position:absolute;
  }
  div{position:absolute;
  width:700px;
height:500px; } 
#divo{left: 650px;
  border-left:1px solid black;}
</style>
<body onload="generatefaces() ">
  <h1>Matching game</h1>
  <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
  <div id="divi"></div>
  <div id="divo"></div>
  <script>
    var src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png"
    var numberoffaces=5;
    var rightside=document.getElementById("divo");
          var leftside=document.getElementById("divi");
    
    
   function generatefaces(){     
      for (i=0; i<numberoffaces; i++){
      var img=document.createElement("img");
      img.src=src;
      img.width=50;
      img.height=50;
      var x=Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+"px";
      img.style.top=x;
      var y=Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+"px";
      img.style.left=y;

      leftside.appendChild(img);}
     
   var  leftsideimages=leftside.cloneNode(true);
leftside.removeChild(leftside.lastChild) ;
 rightside.appendChild(leftsideimages);
     return;
   }
```

And I want to extend the code to make it do an event when the extra smiley is clicked. so I added the following code

```js
leftside.lastChild.onclick= function next(event){  while (leftside.firstChild){leftside.removeChild(leftside.firstChild)};
                                    
     while (rightside.firstChild){rightside.removeChild(rightside.firstChild)};
    event.stopPropagation();
    numberoffaces += 5;
generatefaces();
    
}
     var thebody=document.getElementByTag(body)[0]; 
    thebody.onclick = function gameOver() {

    alert("Game Over!");



    thebody.onclick = null;

   leftside.lastChild.onclick = null;


};
```

which ended up cancelling all of the smileys.
What do i do to get the code to carry out the generatefaces() function every time the extra smiley is clicked?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, specifically the code Snippets, to put the HTML in the HTML panel, and the CSS in the CSS panel; otherwise there is an `uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected character '<'`.

Comment: Please you could click here and see it on codepen http://codepen.io/fulem/pen/GNEOpP

Comment: Why bother using an inline code snippet if you don't want to make it work anyway?

Comment: Come on guys, I am new here. Still learning how it works and looking for a solution. Only